# How to disable some enum and keep the enum value?

Tags: java, enums

I wrote a library

This library accept the limited options and print the related string.

```
public class Lib {

    public enum Num {
        ZERO,
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lib obj = new Lib();
        obj.print(Num.ONE);
    }

    public void print(Num num) {
        switch (num) {
            case ZERO:
                System.out.println("ZERO is "+Num.ZERO.ordinal());
                break;
            case ONE:
                System.out.println("ONE is "+Num.ONE.ordinal());
                break;
            case TWO:
                System.out.println("TWO is "+Num.TWO.ordinal());
                break;
            case THREE:
                System.out.println("THREE is "+Num.THREE.ordinal());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the new version, I will disable option ONE and TWO

```
    public enum Num {
        ZERO,
        //ONE,
        //TWO,
        THREE
    }
```

How can I keep the correct values after I disabled the options?

Comment: What do you mean by disabling enum? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't use the `ordinal()` method. Define your own field and method.

Comment: Because there are only 2 values left in you enum, `ordinal()` prints other numbers, that's what you mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking. If you change any piece of code and thereby "remove" "names" that formerly existed ... than of course, any "reference" to any of the deleted elements is ... first of all: broken.

In case of an enum, you might prefer to **not** rely on build-in ordinals; instead you could go for this:

```
enum Whatever {
   ONE(1), TWO(2);

   private final int value;

   private Whatever(value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public int getValue() { return value }
```

But you have to be really careful here. For example, if you are **persisting** enum objects (into some sort of database for example) then any such change (adding or removing enum "values") will lead to incompatibilities!

Comment: That is why I need to keep the old value, if "THREE" changed from "3" to "1", it is not consistent with existing data in database

Comment: In my experience: enums and databases don't really make up a good combination. If possible, stay away from that combination. But probably your question indicates that you are "too" late for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what you want to do, but for example you can do this:

```
public enum Num {
        ZERO,
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
}


switch (num) {
            case ZERO:
                System.out.println("ZERO is "+Num.ZERO.ordinal());
                break;
            case THREE:
                System.out.println("ZERO is "+Num.THREE.ordinal());
                break;
            case One:
            case Two:
            default:
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be disable some of enum now onward and keep stored as it is. To support both the things, you should have a method that returns list of enum that will populate on UI. I.E. List getPopulatedOnUi(). That contains those enum list that you needed.
Don't remove from definition itself. keep as it is. because that will throw error for existing as it might be stored into database.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the print() method as below: Instead of *switch*, you can use *for loop* and make the code little bit generic. Now, even when your enum values changes, you need not to make any changes in this code.

It will handle the case , If you disable some enum values in future.

```
    public void print(Num num) {
        for(Num n : Num.values()) {
            if(n == num) {
                System.out.println(n.name()+ " is " + n.ordinal());
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```